# Angular UI - Bootstrap Accordian text area character counters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Accordian in Angular JS and Bootstrap https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

I would like to have a character counter across these inputs so its one universal one that gets updated, my code so far is:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in group" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled" >

<accordion-heading>
        {{group.title}}<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open1, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open1}" ></i>
    </accordion-heading>
                <p>xxxxxxxxx?</p>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="what[$index]" ng-trim="false" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                <br />
                <p>xxxxxxxxx?</p>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" ng-model="city[$index]" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                <br />
                <p>xxxxxxxxx?</p>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  ng-model="car[$index]" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                <br />
                <p>xxxxxxxxxx?</p>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  ng-model="web[$index]" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                <br />
                <p>xxxxxxxxxx?</p>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"  ng-model="file[$index]" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                <br />
</accordion-group>


    <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groupTwo" is-open="status.open">
     <accordion-heading>
        {{group.title}}<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
    </accordion-heading>
                 <p>xxxxxxxxx</p>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" ng-model="skill[$index]" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>
                  <br />
                  <p>xxxxxxxxxx</p>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"  ng-model="proof[$index]" id="input" maxlength="400"></textarea>


</accordion-group>
```

How do I have a counter at the bottom saying x amount of characters used?

Comment: I guess you could just use the ".length" string property and show the result of that?

Comment: I have seen examples of that, but how would it be used in this context?

Comment: The same way you show {{group.title}} you can show, for example, {{proof[$index].length}} I guess? That's if I understand the context and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Sole, do you have a specific reason to have all the ng-models as separate $scope variables? It'd be a lot cleaner if you attached all the properties into your group objects imo.

Comment: @Fissio I am fairly new to Angular, if you can see a cleaner way to do it, then please elaborate?

Comment: You seem to have arrays like `what` and `city` and whatnot - you could just attach all the same indexed things to your group objects like `$scope.groups = [{what: 'whatValue', city: 'cityValue'....]` etc.